How to coerce text using IFS function in Google Sheets?
I have a text in the cell A3 =SCHOOL
I have built a formula in the cell B3
=IFS(A3= "SCHOOL", "ST. XAVIER", A3="COLLEGE", "OXFORD")

But the problem is that, the error is coming that 'SCHOOL' is a text and cannot be coerced to a number. I want to change the values conditionally. Please help me.
B3 should be OXFORD when the value is in A3 as COLLEGE.

tested your formula and it works. can you share copy of your sheet?

you can do:
=IF(A3="SCHOOL",  "ST. XAVIER", 
 IF(A3="COLLEGE", "OXFORD", ))

or:
=SWITCH(A3, "SCHOOL", "ST. XAVIER", "COLLEGE", "OXFORD")


but you can always add (nest) more IF statements:
=IF(A3="SCHOOL",  "ST. XAVIER", 
 IF(A3="COLLEGE", "OXFORD", 
 IF(A3="xxxxxxx", "yyy", )))


=IF(A3="SCHOOL",  "ST. XAVIER", 
 IF(A3="COLLEGE", "OXFORD", 
 IF(A3="xxxxxxx", "yyy", 
 IF(A3="fkhfgkh", "gghjv", ))))

next you can use:
=XLOOKUP(A3, {"SCHOOL", "COLLEGE"}, {"ST. XAVIER", "OXFORD"}, )


or:
=VLOOKUP(A3, {"SCHOOL",  "ST. XAVIER"; 
              "COLLEGE", "OXFORD"}, 2, )



If more than two arguments?

@RanjanKumarSingh try SWITCH from updated answer

Yeh, exactly I need.
